# MySQL's ibdata file is getting big and the size doesn't reflect how much data I have

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

The size of MySQL ibdata is 4GB, but I don't think the data I have should take that much disk space. I am using MySQL InnoDB storage engine. Am I doing something wrong with configuration? How do I reclaim the disk space because deleting rows didn't help at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete stuff, the records are only marked as unused/free and will be reused when you insert more data. You cannot reclaim disc space without doing a full dump/reload of the database though(unless you have used the innodb_per_table option)

See more info here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-and-removing.html